# How to avoid hard code attributeName when using CriteriaUpdate Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ClassA{
    public static final String COL_VERSION = "VersionABC";
    public static final String COL_DATA = "DataABC";

    @Column(name = COL_VERSION)
    private String version;

    @Column(name = COL_DATA)
    private String data;

}
```

And in my DAO:

```
EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = mgr.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<ClassA> criteriaUpdate = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(ClassA.class);
Root<ClassA> root = criteriaUpdate.from(ClassA.class);
criteriaUpdate.set(root.get("data"), newData);
if (//condition){
    criteriaUpdate.set(root.get("version"), newVersion);    
}

mgr.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

This code worked, but how to use `ClassA.COL_VERSION` and `ClassA.COL_DATA`  instead of using hard code "data" and "version" ?

Answer (score 2):

```
try like this it should be _. instead of ._


EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = mgr.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<ClassA> criteriaUpdate = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(ClassA.class);
Root<ClassA> root = criteriaUpdate.from(ClassA.class);
criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(ClassA_.data), newData);
if (//condition){
    criteriaUpdate.set(root.get(ClassA_.version), newVersion);    
}

mgr.createQuery(criteriaUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

refer  http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaUpdate

Answer (score 1):

You can use metamodel classes which can be generated automatically. If you are using maven to control dependency, then add this plugin which will generate metamodel classes for you.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>process</id>
       <goals>
         <goal>process</goal>
       </goals>
       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
       <configuration>
         <processors>
           <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
         </processors>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Once metamodel classes are generated, you can use attribute name like...

`root.get(ClassA_.data)` instead of `root.get("data")`.